# How to filter and get shipping address on checkout page based on custom address attribute?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

I want to filter the shipping address visible on the Magento2 checkout page based on a custom address attribute.
I want to show only those address which has the required custom attribute value in them.

From which Magento2 class/file this comes on the checkout page? where I can add my logic.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible look into the class

\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider::getConfig()

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php#L291

\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider::getCustomerData()

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php#L377

The key `customerData` contains `addresses` where all the addresses could be loaded into checkout here.
Plugin into \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider::getConfig()
And change the result of key `addresses` for your purpose